# In a makefile, variable not overwritten despite showing it has a different value and which also results in wrong ifeq

Tags: makefile

Consider this Makefile,

```
#!/bin/sh
IS_FIRSTRUN:=false

.PHONY: firstrun
firstrun: export IS_FIRSTRUN:=true
firstrun: run

.PHONY: run
run: 
        @echo "IS_FIRSTRUN is <${IS_FIRSTRUN}>"
ifeq (${IS_FIRSTRUN},true)
        @echo "In true statement, IS_FIRSTRUN after that is <${IS_FIRSTRUN}>"
endif

ifeq (${IS_FIRSTRUN},false)
        @echo "In false statement, IS_FIRSTRUN after that is <${IS_FIRSTRUN}>"
endif
```

When I run the command, *make run*, this happens.

```
make run
IS_FIRSTRUN is <false>
In false statement, IS_FIRSTRUN after that is <false>
```

When I run the command, *make firstrun*, this happens.

```
make firstrun
IS_FIRSTRUN is <true>
In false statement, IS_FIRSTRUN after that is <true>
```

As you can see when *make firstrun* is carried out, I expected the if condition for true to be executed but it does not. I would like to know why and what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use target-specific variables in `ifeq` conditional statements.

Conditional statements are parsed by make during its first pass when it reads in makefiles.  Target-specific variables are not defined until the second pass, when make is actually building targets and running recipes.  See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) where it says:

> As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).

Just because the `ifeq` appears in the middle of the recipe doesn't mean it's part of the recipe: only lines indented with a TAB are part of the recipe.

If you want the check to be done on a target-specific variable you need to use shell conditional constructs in your recipe, not make conditional constructs, something like this:

```
run: 
        @echo "IS_FIRSTRUN is <${IS_FIRSTRUN}>"
        @if [ '${IS_FIRSTRUN}' = true ]; then \
            echo "In true statement, IS_FIRSTRUN after that is <${IS_FIRSTRUN}>"; \
        fi

        @if [ '${IS_FIRSTRUN}' = false ]; then \
            echo "In false statement, IS_FIRSTRUN after that is <${IS_FIRSTRUN}>"; \
        fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This really helped a lot.